# Is it possible to make 'generic' casting in Java?

Tags: java

I have following function:

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                        JTable table, Object value,
                        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                        int row, int column)
{

    if( value instanceof JTextField ) {
        return ( JTextField )value;
    } else if( value instanceof JComboBox ) {
        return ( JComboBox )value;
    } else if( value instanceof JCheckBox ) {
        return ( JCheckBox )value;
    }

    return this;
}
```

and I wonder whether there is a possibility to make it more generic, something like this:

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                        JTable table, Object value,
                        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                        int row, int column)
{
    return ( CastToWhatItShouldBeCasted )value;
}
```

or something else which will let me to use any component type in there without adding the next if statement.

Comment: Note that such a cast does *nothing* except check the type of the object referenced by `value`. It does not *change* anything. The returned object will still be the same with or without the cast (or with a simple cast to `Component`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you want. This would compile:

```
if (value instanceof Component)
    return (Component) value;

return this;
```

But the meaning would change a bit. It would return the value also for other components than the given three.

This will be equivalent of your code, but a bit shorter:

```
if (value instanceof JTextField || value instanceof JComboBox|| value instanceof JCheckBox )
    return (Component) value;

return this;
```

Comment: More appropriate would be `return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(...)` (assuming ofc that he's extending the default renderer like he should.)

Comment: Thanks, I was trying just: return (Component)value; but it was crashing without the if you've added.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use java generics as you wrote? If so your code will look like this:

```
@Override
public <T extends Component> T getTableCellRendererComponent(
                        JTable table, T value,
                        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                        int row, int column)
{
    return value;
}
```